# How to save multiple data to database in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I try to use for loop to save the multiple data to database but the database only show the last value. I can't figure out which part is error.

This is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="receipt_details")
public class ReceiptDetails {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="ordered_food")
private String ordered_food;

@Column(name="quantity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name="price")
private double price;
```

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.fyp6.model.ReceiptDetails;

public interface ReceiptDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<ReceiptDetails, Integer> {

}
```

Service

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.fyp6.model.ReceiptDetails;
import com.example.fyp6.repo.ReceiptDetailsRepository;

@Service
public class ReceiptDetailsServiceImpl implements ReceiptDetailsService {

@Autowired
private ReceiptDetailsRepository receiptDetailsRepo;

@Override
public ReceiptDetails save(ReceiptDetails receiptDetails) {
    return receiptDetailsRepo.save(receiptDetails);
}
```

}

Controller

```
//Save invoice details
List<Item> cart = (List<Item>) session.getAttribute("cart");    
for(Item item : cart) {
ReceiptDetails receiptDetails = new ReceiptDetails(); 
receiptDetails.setId(receipt.getReceipt_id());
receiptDetails.setPrice(item.getFood().getFood_price());
receiptDetails.setQuantity(item.getQuantity());
receiptDetails.setOrdered_food(item.getFood().getFood_name());
receiptDetailsService.save(receiptDetails);
}
```

I can't figure out which part is error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
receiptDetails.setId(receipt.getReceipt_id());
```

Here is the catch. You save all entities with the same id. Therefore only 1 is shown in the database

Comment: I remove receiptDetails.setId(receipt.getReceipt_id()) and   added  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="receipt_id") private Receipt receipt. It is worked !!! Thank you so much

Comment: @JYong consider accepting answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Boug’s answer. Try to use autogenerated value to populate your Primary key. Or use composite key to make your record unique.

PS: you can use saveAll() instead of save().